# How to horizontally append data written to an excel file in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a Raw data sheet that I have done some processing on, (grouped by countries and gotten top six values along with the total amount), all in all I have below data that I want to append like what is shown below and have no idea how to go on about it.

[I want to append this data every day when I run my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7ZcU.png)

[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwyzP.png)

```
This is the code I have used:

import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime

IDD_Incoming_path = 'D:/Dashboard_Script/New_format/DailyRev_IDD_Incoming.xlsx'
DF_IDD_Incoming = pd.read_excel(IDD_Incoming_path)

# Group by 'COUNTRY_NAME' and sum the 'VOICE_AMOUNT' for each country
IDD_Incoming_grouped_df = DF_IDD_Incoming.groupby('COUNTRY_NAME')['VOICE_AMOUNT'].sum().reset_index()

# Get the top six countries based on total 'VOICE_AMOUNT'
DF_IDD_TopSix = IDD_Incoming_grouped_df.nlargest(6, 'VOICE_AMOUNT')

output_excel_path = 'D:/Dashboard_Script/Dashboard.xlsx'

with pd.ExcelWriter(output_excel_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    # Write the top six countries and their total amounts to the Dashboard.xlsx file
    DF_IDD_TopSix.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='IDD_Incoming', index=False, startrow=0, header=True)  # Use header=True for the first write

   
    # Write "Total" under the first column and get the sum of values under the second column
    writer.sheets['IDD_Incoming'].cell(row=writer.sheets['IDD_Incoming'].max_row + 1, column=1, value='Total')
    writer.sheets['IDD_Incoming'].cell(row=writer.sheets['IDD_Incoming'].max_row, column=2, value=f'=SUM(B2:B{1 + len(DF_IDD_TopSix)})')
    
    
     # Write the current date at the top of the first column
    current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    writer.sheets['IDD_Incoming'].cell(row=writer.sheets['IDD_Incoming'].max_row + 1, column=1, value=current_date)
```